# Google Analytics tracking not working in OOB SL4 app using Microsoft Silverlight Analytical Framework

Tags: silverlight-4.0, google-analytics

I am using the [MSAF library](http://msaf.codeplex.com/) for my Silverlight Google action tracking, however I cannot get it to work out of browser/offline and there is very little info about it in the wild.

I run fiddler and can see the hits being [logged on the live site](http://www.pokerdiy.com/poker-blinds-timer.aspx), however, when my app is offline or running OOB, actions never show up in fiddler or the GA results.

As per the .chm file, I have added

```
 <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects><mwa:WebAnalyticsService/></Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

to my app.xaml and have various tracking actions (code and xaml). As I mentioned, the actions are definitely being tracked correctly in GA, just not when OOB.

Where is the data stored when running oob (I am connected 24/7) or is it stored locally anyway and then sent up periodically?

How can I test it or get it working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been [identified as a bug in MSAF](http://msaf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=228657) and will be fixed soon...